# keep body mesh from poking through clothes mesh when posing with armature

Tags: mesh, modifiers, armature, pose-mode

i've made an armature for my character and parented it to both the shirt and body mesh of my character, but when i pose the character the body mesh pokes through. i don't particularly want to add any physics to my clothing as i'm not going for realism but if there is indeed some physical property or modifier i could use to prevent this, i would love to know. i tried shrinkwrap modifier with .001 offset, but the result was about the same.
[image]

[image]
[image]

the file, if needed: https://pasteall.org/blend/eed85f2ab37944bb804b230529c633df

thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't to delete all hidden part of body that is not visible thanks to cloth?

Comment: i don't really want to destroy the mesh, since i want to put other clothes on the character later... :(

Comment: you can use the Mask modifier in order to hide a vertex group

Answer (score 0):

You can hide/delete the mesh which is not visible due to clothes or you can adjust the clothes by going into edit mode such that body isn't visible

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the vertices that you want to make invisible and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to assign them to a new group, then give a *Mask* modifier to your object, and in the *Vertex Group* field, choose the vertex group you've created, press on the *Invert* button to make the vertices invisible. You can disable the modifier whenever you want if you keyframe its visibility.

[image]